# Removing plsql type from query string with RegEx in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bunch of strings that look something like this:

```
Select my_type(thing1, thing2, thing3) From a_table where this_other_thing = 'blah' and the_last_thing = a_code
```

I need to be able to remove the "my_type(" and the closing ")" from around the "thing1, thing2, thing3".

I can match the first part with

```
/my_type[(]/i
```

but I've been unable to snag just the closing parenthesis.  I'm using javascript for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you can get the results:

```js
var str = "Select my_type(thing1, thing2, thing3) From a_table where this_other_thing = 'blah' and the_last_thing = a_code";

var results = str.match(/my_type\((.*?)\)/i);

// All the parameters as a string
console.log(results[1]);

// Each parameter in an array
console.log(results[1].split(/, */));
```

To do a replacement, match the entire block, and replace it with the parameters inside:

```js
var str = "Select my_type(thing1, thing2, thing3) From a_table where this_other_thing = 'blah' and the_last_thing = a_code";

var result = str.replace(/my_type\((.*?)\)/i, '$1');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, FrankerZ.  Works perfectly.